# Working with elements on two dictionaries. Ranking job posting and candidates and assigning best candidate to best post

Tags: python, dictionary, matching

I have two instances in my program: agents and firms.
I want a new class to work so that I can control the assignment of agents to firms.

The class I created has two dictionaries. I add posts and candidates to each dictionary. Each dictionary is keyed by the firm or agent ID. I had it work in other modules of my program.

I call the method to assign_post that would match candidates to posts. But it does not seem to work.

The whole class is:

```
class Posting(object):

    def __init__(self):
        self.available_postings = {}
        self.candidates = {}

    def add_post(self, firm):
        self.available_postings[firm.get_firm_id()] = firm

    def add_candidate(self, agent):
        self.candidates[agent.get_id()] = agent

    def assign_post(self):
        # Rank positions by wage and rank employees by qualifications
        # Make a match

        while len(self.candidates) > 0 and len(self.available_postings) > 0:
            # Best qualification
            dummy_best = self.candidates.popitem()
            for key in self.candidates.keys():
                if dummy_best.get_qual() > self.candidates[key].get_qual():
                    dummy_best = self.candidates[key]
            # Higher wage
            dummy_higher = self.available_postings.popitem()
            for key in self.available_postings.keys():
                if dummy_higher.set_wage_base() > self.available_postings[key].set_wage_base():
                    dummy_higher = self.available_postings[key]
            # Assignment. Firm has method add_employee
            dummy_higher.add_employee(dummy_best)
            # Remove agent and firm from list
            del self.available_postings[dummy_higher.get_firm_id()]
            del self.candidates[dummy_best.get_id()]
```

Comment: More information. I added print statements to check if the code is being executed. I found that candidates and firms are being added correctly. However, when starting assign_post(), which is being called, dictionaries are empty? post added {0: <firms.Firm object at 0x0000000007C904A8>}
post added {1: <firms.Firm object at 0x0000000007C904E0>}
candidate added {1: <agents.Agent object at 0x0000000007C90128>}
candidate added {3: <agents.Agent object at 0x0000000007C90198>}
candidate added {6: <agents.Agent object at 0x0000000007C90240>}
start assignment 0 0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The mistake in your code is that you lose the item that received from`popitem()`, in the case where it is not the best/higher. Try to receive element without removing it from dict, do assignment and after that remove it.

Comment: No. I think it is before that. I am sure the posts and candidates are being added to the dictionaries. But, when assign_post() runs, printing the dictionaries returns 0, empty. @alexlisovoy

Comment: when you do `dummy_best = self.candidates.popitem()`, you removed this element from `self.candidates` and try to calculate best qualification. If it found, you rewrite it `dummy_best = self.candidates[key]` and lose element received from `self.candidates.popitem()`

Comment: Yes. But before that, I test the size of the dictionary and it is empty. So it is not even going inside 'while'. I don't know why the dictionary is going away. I test after the adding and it contains the item all right. Thanks anyway.

Comment: Are you sure that is the same instance Posting?

Comment: That's it. I was calling communications.Posting() in general, without having a specific instance! Thanks. However, I think I made this mistake because I have another class statistics.Statistics() that I have no instance for and yet I can calculate, print, and make graphs with the statistics that I being calculated... does it mean I am calculating new statistics every time I call a method? I think so. Because all methods are independent of previous information. For the graph I output a txt every month. Thanks a bunch! Do I have to get an instance of statistics?